# При закачивание сайта на хостинг в консоли возникает ошибка

Tags: jquery

Проблема немного странная, при закачивание сайта на хост в консоле возникает ошибка

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of null
    at window.particlesJS (http://fellpayeer.ru/lib/particles.min.js:9:22397)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://fellpayeer.ru/js/js.js:1:704)
    at j (http://fellpayeer.ru/lib/jquery-3.1.0.min.js:2:29568)
    at k (http://fellpayeer.ru/lib/jquery-3.1.0.min.js:2:29882) undefined
jquery-3.1.0.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of null
```

Проблема заключается в том что при запуске этого же сайта на локальном хосте (Open Server) ни каких ошибок нет, все работает как и положено! В чем может быть дело? В интернете читал что людям помогает замена версии jquery с 3 на 2, я пробывал, не помогло. Что делать?

Comment: Вообще-то у вас вместо страницы сервер отдает 500 ошибку. js тут не при чем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, какой-то ваш скрипт, зависящий от jQuery или других внешних библиотек - начинает выполняться до загрузки этих библиотек.

> На локальной машине все внешние библиотеки хранятся локально на вашем ПК, и загружаются быстро. На сервере же - загрузка их браузером происходит чуть дольше, и в такие моменты ваш скрипт может срабатывать до загрузки библиотек.

Решается просто - в своих скриптах весь код, зависящий от внешних библиотек привязывайте к событиям загрузки этих библиотек. Например, для CKEditor:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(event) {
  # Ваш код, использующий загруженный редактор CKEditor
});
```

А код, использующий DOM, привязывайте к полной загрузке DOM'а:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  # Ваш код, работающий с DOM
});
```

---

Конкретно в вашем случае, в файле `js/js.js` у вас вызывается метод `particlesJS("particles-js"...`, вызывается до загрузки DOM'а, из-за чего внешний скрипт просто не находит тег, к которому скрипт применять, и выбрасывает ошибку. Привяжите вызов `particlesJS` к событию загрузки DOM'а:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  particlesJS("particles-js", {
    # Ваши параметры для particlesJS
  });
});
```

Comment: Вы на сайт-то к вопрошающему заглянули прежде, чем этот ответ написали?

Comment: @Visman, по вашему предложению заглянул. И понял, что действительно ответил верно. В файле js.js, particlesJS вызывается до загрузки DOM'а. Спасибо вам за подсказку. Дополню ответ.

Comment: Не помогло оба файла которые указываются в ошибки уже обвернуты в $(document).ready(function() { }), и все ровно вылетает ошибка

Comment: Вы про файлы `particles.min.js` и `jquery-3.1.0.min.js`? Они рапортуют об ошибке, но причина ошибки не в них, а в вашем файле `js.js`, попробуйте обернуть вызов `particlesJS` в событие, как указано в конце моего ответа.

Comment: @ДмитрийК., то есть 500 ошибка сервера, которая сейчас у вас на сайте, это нормально?