# Проблема с particles.js

Tags: javascript

Скачивал библиотеку с официального сайта и решил проверить демо на локальном сервере, в итоге в консоли выдает ошибку:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'speed' of undefined 
>   at new pJS (particles.js:146) 
>   at window.particlesJS (particles.js:1517) 
>   at initParticles ((index):62) 
>   at (index):64

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/561779/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: Покажите код инициализации particles.js

Comment: particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/particles.json', function() {
  console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
});